Inconsistent usage of the definite article
There is a piece of text:

My friends live in a small town. It is a new town. The streets in
the town are broad and straight. There are beautiful buildings in
them. The town is very green, and so the air is fresh. There are some
beautiful parks and gardens in the town. People like to go there
after work. In the evening you can hear the sounds of music from the
parks. There are some schools, some libraries, a supermarket, a
hospital, a theater, some cinemas, some clinics and some kindergartens
in the town.

The text is from a textbook and is related to the usage of articles.
I've highlighted the parts that are confusing. We use the definite article before 'streets' in 'The streets ...' because we don't mean streets in general; we mean the streets of the town. If I follow this logic, then I need to put the definite article before 'people' in 'People like ...', as we don't refer to people in general but rather to the residents of the town. However, for some reason, the author didn't include the definite article there. I don't understand the logic of not using the definite article in this case. From my point of view, if we use the definite article in the first sentence of interest (the one with 'streets'), we should use it in the second sentence of interest (the one with 'people'), but this isn't the case. So the question is: What's wrong with my reasoning?

People without an article means 'people in general'. Yes, I know that logically it must refer to local residents, since visitors wouldn't go 'after work', but to a native speaker it would sound odd to say 'the people' - as though only locals enjoyed the parks.

@KateBunting I felt that awkwardness, but was unable to spot the idea behind the presented difference. Thanks as always!

"the people" is for: The people of [geographical name place] or further qualified. Compare: Apples are good for you. People like to go there. It does NOT refer to just residents of the town as Kate said in another way.

@Lambie I think you should consider the sentence about people in full. It contains the phrase "after work." It's highly improbable that people from other cities will go to the town described to spend their time in the park. Therefore, the author is definitely talking about the residents of the town.

Read Kate's point. She is saying the same thing and I just gave an example. It's a general statement about people. Some of them could come from just outside the town or be on their way to another town after work, stopping there.

OP's query concerns the choice of articles in these sentences:


The streets in the town are broad and straight.
People like to go there after work.


1. Why "The Streets"?
The definite article in the first sentence refers to a defined set of streets in the town. It emphasizes the major or notable streets that are broad and straight, but this does not exclude the possibility of narrower or winding streets existing in the town.
Consider these examples and their explanations:

The guests at the party were making a lot of noise. (This doesn’t imply all the guests—some might have been quiet.)
The apples at the supermarket were rotten. (It generalizes about the apples, even though some may be of good quality.)
The boys of the school are naughty. (This doesn’t exclude the possibility of disciplined students.)

Similarly, "the streets" generalizes about the main streets without requiring an exhaustive inclusion of all streets.
2. Why No Article with "People"?
In the second sentence, "people" is used without the definite article because it refers to people in general, not a specific or defined group.
Compare:


People are always looking for a bargain. (This refers to people in general—no specific group is implied.)
The people have made their choice. (Here, "the people" refers to a specific group, such as the voters in a country.)


In this context, "people" simply refers to those in the town who like to visit the parks, without emphasizing any fixed or identifiable subset of residents.
Final Note:
The use of the definite article ("the streets," "the people") does not always imply all members of a group, just a defined or notable subset.
Conversely, omitting the definite article ("people") does not imply some—it simply refers to people in a general or undefined sense.

Thanks, James! Your answer has definitely clarified the topic at hand. I just don’t really understand why the residents of the town are considered people in general here. They definitely aren’t people in general. If we think about all the people in the world, the residents of the town form a specific group of people. On the other hand, I feel intuitively that using the definite article before "people" in the sentence discussed isn’t the right thing.

@snailontheslope I have included examples of "the people" meaning the voters.  You’re right that the town’s residents form a specific group, but using "people" without "the" makes the sentence more general. It suggests that visiting the park is typical behavior, without emphasizing a fixed or strictly defined group. Adding "the" would feel too restrictive, implying all residents or a formalized group. The phrasing reflects a general observation about habits rather than specifying exactly who visits the park.

@snailontheslope: You are approaching it backwards.The world does not dictate language. Rather the speaker presents the situation according to the various degrees of focus they have in mind. The statement about people coming after work is intended to be a general one about the town's amenities. Those amenities are the focus, not the citizenry.  "People" without definite article is simply a way of not focusing on this town's citizenry.  They are not special in their liking of its parks and gardens.

All towns have streets, hence the streets.  There's no need to say "The town has streets" first, to introduce them.
Compare:

Up in the mountains there is a camp beside a lake. The camp is for girls aged  8 to 16. Every morning the campers swim in the lake. The water in the lake is very cold.

To say "The people like to go there" would be wrong, as you haven't previously talked about any people in particular yet, and that's because the passage is not about a particular group of people, but people in general, that is, it is not focusing on this town's citizenry but talking about how the town's parks and gardens attract people after work.



The streets in the town are broad and straight.


The OP suggests that the definite article is used here because it is referring to a specific set of streets: the streets of this town, and no other town. But that's not the main emphasis. Suppose there was no definite article:


Streets in the town are broad and straight.


We would still know that the reference is to a specific set of streets in a specific town.
So why the article? I would read it as a subtle emphasis that we are talking about all the streets in the town, not just some of them. Suppose I visited the town having read the report. If there were ten streets, I would expect all ten of them to be "broad and straight."


There are some beautiful parks and gardens in the town. People like to go there after work.


This is the opposite case. Yes, the reference is to the people in a specific town. But in context, we would not read the report as describing all of them using the "parks and gardens" at the same time. If there were a thousand residents in the town, but only fifty of them were walking in the park on a given evening, the report would still be true.

Peter, thanks for a very clear explanation!

When you say "a specific set of streets in a specific town" do you mean a partial subset of the town's streets?  Or all of the streets in the town?

@TimR I meant all the streets in the town, in contrast to all other possible streets in the world. And, according to my understanding, Peter means the same.

@TimR, What he said! (I do see now that my answer was ambiguous at that point. Sorry about that.)
